# Theming AppCompat ActionBar

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat

I am trying to support devices down to API level 9 by using the AppCompat library.  I am trying to theme the ActionBar using the [example theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#StyleExample) from Google but it keeps telling me that any item named android:action* `requires API level 11 (current min is 9)`.  I am targeting 18.  If I use the stuff directly from the example why is it breaking? And can anyone help me figure out how to theme the ActionBar using the AppCompat library from API level 9?

Comment: What exactly is breaking? And it doesn't matter what you're targeting, what matters is your minimum API level.

Comment: I want to be able to theme the Actionbar on API level below 11.  The example says it should work for 2.1 (API 7) and up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:action*` items are only available with API 11 and above. In order to support different API levels, Android contains various `values` directories. If you look at your project's folder structure, you will most likely see directories for `res/values` and `res/values-11` and perhaps a few other ones. As you might have guessed, the `11` stands for API 11, which means that themes that are only available in API 11 and above should be included here. The `values` directory is your base one.

Therefore, for your example, you need to split up the themes file into two different ones. The parts that contain `android:action*` should be in a themes file in the `values-11` folder, and the other ones can stay in the base `values` folder. Android takes care of automatically choosing the proper theme.

You should really read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), especially the parts near the bottom about applying themes. It discusses how you can apply themes to different API levels.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are trying to use is only available from API 11 up. 
You won't be able to use in devices that have API level 9 like you wanted to.

**requires API level 11 (current min is 9)**

You can run the example in devices with Android 3.0 and up, but for that you will have to change your Manifest file minSdkVersion to at least 11.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: I understand what the error means.  I'm asking how to get around it without increasing my minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all the items with `android:action*` and leave only those with `action*` (without the `android` namespace).

This works for me but I got my style from this wonderful style generator for action bar: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/